# Using the YS-IRTM with an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, c++, softwareserial

Picked up a YS-IRTM IR Transmitter/Receiver module to do some testing for a project. There's not a lot of details on it but eventually came across two very important sources:

Translated Module Datasheet: https://docplayer.net/101050357-Nec-infrared-codec-module-ver1-0-ys-irtm.html

Examples: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=359707.msg2861077#msg2861077

I've been trying to get this working for a few days and so far haven't gotten anything. Need to reach out before I pull out whatever hair I have left.

BTW, new to this and may have easily missed something.

Wiring Diagram

```
Arduino Uno    YS-IRTM
5v          -> 5v
GND         -> GND
0 RX        -> TXD
1 TX        -> RXD
```

Code

```
int icb = 0;
SoftwareSerial ir_mod(0, 1);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial){}
  Serial.println("Setup IR Serial");
  ir_mod.begin(9600);
  while(!ir_mod){}
  Serial.println("IR Serial Ready");
}

void loop(){
  if(ir_mod.available() > 0){
    icb = ir_mod.read();
    Serial.print(" 0x");
    Serial.println(icb, HEX);
  }
}
```

Current Output

```
Setup IR Serial
IR Serial Ready
```

Nothing will happen if I try to interact with the Receiver with any IR Transmitter (like a TV/AC Remote) but if I disconnect and reconnect the power, I get " 0xFFFFFFFF". Then nothing.

Comment: edit your question so that it says that ... right now your question is still unclear ... then delete your comment

Comment: I found these links:
https://www.cnx-software.com/2017/04/20/karls-home-automation-project-part-4-mqtt-bridge-updated-to-use-ys-irtm-ir-receiver-transmitter-with-nodemcu/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401838/ir-tx-rx-issues-for-ys-irtm-receiver-transmitter

Answer (score 1):

Default baud for module is 9600 unless you previous set it diffrent as per the datasheet A1 F3 ## 00 00 I believe

Comment: I did play with the baud rate. I reset the device to set it back to default which meant it was reset to 9600. That means the baud rate to the device is 9600 and the rate to the monitor is 115200.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to this but if I am not mistaken, you seem to have connected the IR module to Arduino Hardware Serial while trying to communicate with the module via SoftwareSerial. Try using Arduino pins 2 and 3 for the SoftwareSerial instead of pins 0 and 1. Forgive me if I got it all wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I did think of that so during my testing, I had used other pins, such as 8 and 9 but no change.